# In C Use 64 bit ints or 16 bit ints for performance on a 64 bit CPU?

Tags: performance, caching, 64-bit, memory-alignment

On a 64 bit CPU with decent sized cache, which will lead to better performance in a C application which uses  many fairly large arrays of structures of int: using 64 bit ints so that everything is always aligned on 8 byte boundaries, which the CPU likes, or 16 bit ints so that there are more array elements in the cache ?
Has anyone ever benchmarked this sort of issue ?

Comment: Which CPU (ARM, 80x86, ...); and what exactly are you doing with what data? E.g. if it's something the compiler can optimize to use SIMD then the code might end up doing much larger aligned reads regardless. For portability, the solution is to use something like `uint_fast16_t` so that you can blame the compiler if/when it doesn't optimize.

Comment: Personally I am using an Intel Core i7 ; not the most recent. I have this library that was written back when 16 bit ints were the norm. It uses lots of threading. I don't know about Vectorization since i did not write it. I have the source and can rebuild it after redefining the ints, (currently 32 bits) to be 16 bits. I am just wondering if it is likely to be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

On mainstream 64-bit processors (ie. x86-64 and arm64), **the size of integers has significant impact on the performance of scalar instructions**.

However, it is generally **better to work on the smallest possible type if the code is vectorized** since SIMD instructions work on fixed-size internal SIMD vectors (128 bits for SSE, 256 for AVX/AVX2, 512 for AVX-512, 128 for Neon). Note that using types of different sizes can introduces quite-expensive conversions or reduce the capacity of some compiler to vectorize efficiently the loops (recent mainstream optimizing compilers are relatively good to vectorize code in this case although the generated code is often not optimal).

Regarding *caches*, arrays with **smaller integer items can be loaded faster from the memory** hierarchy. Indeed, the L1/L2 cache are generally quite small, so if an array can fit in such caches, the accesses to this array will be faster (lower latency and higher throughput). The impact is particularly visible for random accesses.

Regarding the *alignment*, its does not generally have a significant impact on *x86-64 platforms* as compilers and runtimes do a good job to align arrays efficiently and processors are optimized to access unaligned data (even using SIMD instruction). For example, `malloc`/`realloc` returns memory addresses aligned on 16-bytes by default on most x86-64/arm64 platforms.

Comment: There's some issues for x86_64 with this comment. For modern incarnations (Haswell and forward) there is no data alignment penaltiy. There are  a couple of corner casessuch as crossing a page boundary that takes a ~10 cycle hit. Also, any access across a cache line once the split registers have been exhausted (VTune can tell you) will take a hit too. But you have to exhust the split regs to have it happen.

Comment: 2-- Do not use the partial registers  like AL, AH, AX, etc. They cause a false data dependency and will cause pipeline stalls. (WEell, you cna use them but you ould have to mae sure they didnt step on each other like they tend to do)